# Emmet to generate html

Tags: html, emmet

What is an Emmet equivalent ( Zen coding ) that generates the following:

```
<div id="main">
<article class="isActive">
    <ul class="list">
        <li id="item1" class="item">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                </div>
                <p>
                    content
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

article tag can be repeated more than once and ui tag within article can be repeated more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
#main>(article.isActive>ul.list>li.item#item$*2>(div.inner>div.content>img^p{content}))*3
```

3 is the number of article tags.
2 is the number of ui tags inside article.